# Сохранить объект из ссылки и передать в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ссылка:

```
<a href="#" data-productId="2124" data-title="Цветы какие-то" data-smth="smth">Добавить в корзину</a>
```

Как при клике на ссылку передать всю ссылку (объект) в функцию? будет ли работать такое:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
  var this = this;
  functionname(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` в обработчике - кликнутый элемент.

```js
function functionname(aLink) {
  console.log(aLink);
}

$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  functionname(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-productId="2124" data-title="Цветы какие-то" data-smth="smth">Добавить в корзину</a>
```